# New column based on values from other columns in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe df which looks like this

| min | max | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 9 | 7 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 10 | 3 |

I want to create a new column df['accuracy'] which tells me the accuracy if the df['value'] is in between df['min'] and df['max'] such that the new dataframe looks like

| min | max | value | Accuracy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 9 | 7 | Accurate |
| 3 | 4 | 10 | Not Accurate |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | Accurate |
| 4 | 10 | 3 | Not Accurate |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apply()` method of `pandas`, [refer link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
def accurate(row):  
    if row['value'] >= row['min'] and row['value'] <= row['max']:
        return 'Accurate'
    return 'Not Accurate'

df['Accuracy'] = df.apply(lambda row: accurate(row), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that there's no need to use a lambda function here. Instead, just pass it like so: `df.apply(accurate, axis=1)`