# New column based values based on values of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df which looks like this:

| number | category | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | category1 | 5 | 10 | 20 |
| 30 | category2 | 6 | 12 | 24 |
| 25 | category3 | 4 | 9 | 15 |
| 10 | category2 | 4 | 12 | 16 |

I want 2 extra columns called `df['number_upper']` and `df['number_lower]`.

`df['number_upper']` should ADD `cat_1` values to `df['number']` when `category == category1` and should add `cat_2 values` to `df['number']` if `category == category2` and add `cat_3` values to `df['number']` when `category == category3`

The same way,

`df['number_lower']` should SUBTRACT `cat_1` values to `df['number']` when `category == category1` and should subtract `cat_2` values to `df['number']` if `category == category2` and subtract `cat_3` values to `df['number']` when `category == category3`.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

| number | category | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | number_upper | number_lower |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | category1 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 25 | 15 |
| 30 | category2 | 6 | 12 | 24 | 42 | 18 |
| 25 | category3 | 4 | 9 | 15 | 40 | 10 |
| 10 | category2 | 4 | 12 | 16 | 22 | -2 |

Comment: Could you fix the table?

Comment: It should be fixed if you refresh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New column based on values from other columns in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191512/new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-in-python)

Comment: No that is a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) with rename columns names for match values in column and add or subtract column:

```
d = {'cat_1':'category1','cat_2':'category2','cat_3':'category3'}
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['category'])
a = df.rename(columns=d).reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
print (a)
[5, 12, 15, 12]

df['number_upper'] = df['number'].add(a)
df['number_lower'] = df['number'].sub(a)
print (df)
   number   category  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  number_upper  number_lower
0      20  category1      5     10     20            25            15
1      30  category2      6     12     24            42            18
2      25  category3      4      9     15            40            10
3      10  category2      4     12     16            22            -2
```

If some values not match are created as missing values (NaN):

```
print (df)
   number   category  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3
0      20  category1      5     10     20
1      30  category2      6     12     24
2      25  category3      4      9     15
3      10  category4      4     12     16 <- change data

d = {'cat_1':'category1','cat_2':'category2','cat_3':'category3'}
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['category'])
a = df.rename(columns=d).reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
print (a)
[5, 12, 15, NaN]

df['number_upper']  = df['number'].add(a)
df['number_lower']  = df['number'].sub(a)
print (df)
   number   category  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3  number_upper  number_lower
0      20  category1      5     10     20          25.0          15.0
1      30  category2      6     12     24          42.0          18.0
2      25  category3      4      9     15          40.0          10.0
3      10  category4      4     12     16           NaN           NaN
```